# 404 error when string interpolating a fetch through input form

Tags: reactjs, api

Using the pokeapi to search by pokemon name, I keep running into this error. I interpolate the input value in the fetch but keep getting this error message. Any advice?

- Error Message
  GET https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/%20mew 404 - xhr.js:178

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState(" ")

let input = " ";
input = search;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const search = await axios (`${URL}${input}`);

        setSearchPokemon({
          name: search.data.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + search.data.name.slice(1), 
          weight: search.data.weight, 
          height: search.data.height, 
          id: search.data.id,
          sprite: search.data.sprites.front_default,
          types: search.data.types.map(pokemon => pokemon.type.name),
          stats: search.data.stats.map(pokemon => pokemon.base_stat),
          abilities: search.data.abilities.map(pokemon => pokemon.ability.name),
          moves: search.data.moves.map(pokemon => pokemon.move.name)
        });
 
    };

    fetchData();

  }, [input]);


  let handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    setSearch(event.target.value)
    event.preventDefault();
  }


<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <input type='text' value={search} onChange={event => setSearch(event.target.value)}/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try to replace the initial value with an empty string instead of " ".
Because from the api address you called there is an extra space %20.

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
```

Comment: That was it, I had an empty string with a space somewhere else and that was throwing it off but I removed the space and its working. Thanks